# Access to same files from two different apps on iOS

Tags: ios, ios6

I have two apps I'm developing at the moment, `App1`, which is downloading files from Dropbox to the iPad, and `App2`. The Dropbox integration is a bit of a hassle, and I'd rather not do it on both apps. So is it possible to save those files from `App1` somewhere that `App2` might access them? I've heard that the Sandboxing of apps got a bit looser in iOS6, but not really sure *how* loose.

I've seen some similar questions here, but they seem to be solved by using URL schemes or sending data to the other app, which isn't really what I'm after.

Any other ideas to solve this will be appreciated.

Comment: Cannot remember exactly, dig along prefixing AppID or bundleID to enable 2 apps accessing the same folder. Previously saw a free version and a paid version accessing the same folder.

Comment: @dklt Any more information on this? Sounds exactly like the kind of info I need.

Comment: Why can't you just write a wrapper which lets you access dropbox with few method calls? In that way it will be portable to any number of applications and also if you are believer of open source you may be generous to put it on Github for other developers :)

Comment: @Owl yeah, I might end up doing just that. It's just that it will be some extra work, as I didn't plan that well ahead and seeing that I might need the Dropbox-stuff in any other apps... (d'oh)

Answer (score 5):

This is possible, but the local method isn't really suitable for large files.

You can use the Keychain to store small amounts of data, similar to NSUserDefaults. The advantage is this can be shared between applications. Refer to http://shaune.com.au/ios-keychain-sharing-data-between-apps/

As for your case, where you want to share files, you *could* encode them to a string and store in the keychain (in my opinion a **very bad idea**), or use a web service (if you're targeting iOS 5 and above, iCloud should do the trick as long as you have the same Team ID for both apps). Refer to http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AboutEntitlements.html

I'd prefer the web service, iCloud should make this a lot easier for you.

Comment: So that means `App1` has to download the files from Dropbox, then store them in iCloud, and then `App2` can download the files from iCloud? Are the files also stored locally with iCloud? The reason I'm downloading the files from Dropbox, is so they'll be available offline.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's able to break the sandbox and access them locally. The Apple docs don't really specify in detail. Best I found was http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/iCloud/iCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH12-SW1 . I assume not, I think it'd do a round trip to the iCloud servers to get the file for the second app, to respect the local file storage sandbox.

Comment: As such, in your situation, I'd stick with the dropbox solution. Remember most people have limited iCloud storage, and Apple suggest making it clear you're using iCloud. It's not ideal, but that the price to pay by having an application controlled on Apple's platform.

Comment: Yeah I'm fearing that this will be the outcome, to actually re-use my Dropbox code and download the files in both apps. Which sucks, shouldn't be that hard to communicate between two apps that I'm developing.

Comment: It does suck, I wholly agree, but if Apple were to relax the sandbox rules for files, then you have a potential to ruin another application's workspace. I can see why they've done it, it's just unfortunate it comes with its downsides...

Comment: Yeah, it would be a mess, but it would be nice to have a way to sandbox a set of apps in some way... Oh, well.

Comment: Sorry to be the bearer of bad news. If you feel it's right, could you accept the answer please? (I wish it was a better answer, I feel your pain!)

Comment: I think I'll just let it stand a couple more days, to see if anyone else comes up with anything. As it stands you'll get the bounty in 6 days as the only answer anyway (:

Answer (score 2):

There is another way you could do this, although it's a very ugly way of doing it, because it makes your information visible to the user (after a fashion, anyway).

One of the only mediums that can be stored, read and write to the same place on the same device is images. You can, in fact, write your information (file, array, web service cache, whatever you want) as the pixel information of an image. Then you can store it without compression locally to a custom album and the other app can access the 'images' in the album and interpret them as the original file. You would have to roll your own header information for you image to indicate the file format, etc, and the user would be able to see the image, although it would mostly look like total nonsense. This is a form as stenography.

Anyway, i don't expect you to accept this as the answer, but I thought i would raise it as a demonstration that with some creative coding you can get around most barriers :)

Comment: Haha! That would be a pretty awesome way to do it, but I don't know if that would be easier than to use the Dropbox-wrapper in both apps. +1 anyway for creativity :D