# Can I retrieve a file in iOS stored in a different app?

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, xamarin

So, I have a game I'm working on, for which I need to access a file from the previous version in the series for continuing from where the player left off. The problem however, is that when I try to retrieve the file from the device it doesn't seem to be able to find this file. I think maybe the OS saves file in a uniquely created folder for each app installed. Is there any way to work around this. I am using code from the following stack overflow post to find my file, which doesn't seem to be working.

[What is the correct way to get the iOS Library folder using Xamarin.iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518440/what-is-the-correct-way-to-get-the-ios-library-folder-using-xamarin-ios)

Oh, and before I forget, the game is being made in Unity, so I'd need an answer that would work with C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not that easy. Apps are Sandboxed in iOS, and so are their files in the Library folder. The [Apple Developer File System Basics Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) states this as "Every App is an island."

That being said, if you are able to modify the original app that hosts the file you're interested in, you could circumvent this problem in several ways (not extensive):

- Store the progress in iCloud, Dropbox, ..., and retain it from there
- Use a technique described [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145978/access-to-same-files-from-two-different-apps-on-ios)

Comment: I agree with Felix, store the file from Game1 in iCloud (or similar cloud based storage) and retrieve it in Game2.

Comment: Yeah, I read a bit more about it too, and that seems like the only way to proceed. We have the data stored on our servers too, but wanted to provide this option for players who chose not to sync with it. I suppose we'll just have to implement with what we have available on the server.